# React - Is it bad practice to use multiple api calls in App component

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I'm working with API data that comes from a table which has many relations with other tables. It uses reference tables and join tables. I have to use this data shared across multiple (if not all) components. Is it bad to make all the api calls right in the App.js/root component? why or why not?

**EDIT**: I am currently using redux, and thinking of storing all the reference table values in global state, so I can do a lookup wherever needed.

example response from API

```
{
  "name": "Adam"
  "schoolId": 2,
  "countryId": 6,
}
```

School example reference table

```
{
  "id": 2,
  "name": "High School",
}
```

Country example reference table

```
{
  "id": 6,
  "name": "Bulgaria"
}
```

App.js

```
function App({ getCountries, getSchools }) {
  // Get all reference table data
  useEffect(() => {
    getCountries();
    getSchools();
    // get...(); All other reference tables
  }, [
    getCountries,
    getSchools,
  ]);

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <div className="App">
        <Router>
          <Fragment>
            <div className="d-flex align-items-stretch wrapper">
              <div id="sidebar">
                <div className="sidemenu position-fixed">
                  <Sidebar />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="content">
                <Navbar />
                <main className="container-fluid">
                  <Switch>
                    <Route component={Routes} />
                  </Switch>
                </main>
              </div>
            </div>
          </Fragment>
        </Router>
      </div>
    </Provider>
  );
}

export default connect(null, { getCountries, getSchools })(App);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling all APIs in the root component of your app poses the risk of your entire app re-rendering whenever a tiny bit of data changes. It is better practice to have child components down the render tree call APIs to fetch the tiny bits of data they need whenever possible, I would say using the **useEffect** hook or the corresponding APIs if you are using class based components. That way, a change in one piece of data causes a particular component to rerender but leaves the other components intact in the DOM.

To further improve performance, you bring in a state management library like Redux into play and make use of caching.

It is not good practice to call APIs to fetch data that isn't necessary yet. That is incurring unnecessary costs and unnecessarily burdening processing resources.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to be needing to use most of these data across most if not all components. I would have to call these api individually in every component to get the data I need for lookup (just like in the example, how I'm getting IDs as the response). I'm using redux currently, and these calls are so that I can fill these values in my store once, so I can use them for lookup across majority of my components.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some suggestions to enhance your React code structure and make it look more professional:

Centralize API Calls: Create a separate api.js file and move all your API-related code there. This approach helps maintain a clean and organized project structure. By centralizing API calls, you can easily manage and modify them when needed.

Utilize Redux for API Integration: Instead of directly calling APIs in your main JSX (JavaScript) files, consider using Redux. In Redux, you can create actions that make API calls, fetch data, and store it in the Redux store. This way, you decouple the API logic from your UI components, making them more reusable and easier to maintain.

Implement Async/Await: When making asynchronous API calls, it's recommended to use async and await keywords. These allow you to write cleaner and more readable asynchronous code. By using await with promises, you can wait for the API response before proceeding further, simplifying error handling and data manipulation.

By following these suggestions, you can improve the structure and organization of your React code, making it more professional and scalable.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to call multiple api from action(redux). for large, reusable, scalable application use **redux** so that you could handle state throughout application.

If your application isn't so big and you want to make all api call from react only then better to use reusable(common) function pass every api to that function for writing clean and concise way.

Comment: I'm using redux currently, and these calls are so I can fill these values in my store so I can use them for lookup across majority of my components.

Comment: @TalalNajam It's good you can call multiple api as you want but use async based on preference.